# Can a basement bathroom be vented through a stack servicing sinks on the floor above?

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent

Can a basement bath (toilet, sink and shower) macerating pump system be workably (not codes) vented into a 3" PVC that vents out the roof if the 3" PVC vent pipe also has 2 vanity sinks on the floor above using the 3" PVC for both a drain and vent (the sinks have traps of course where no smell at the vanities from the pump will exist; and, the basement pump vent will be hooked into the 3" PVC from above it where no vanity drainage can drain into it); and, if done, what are the actual drawbacks? Is the only possible actual problem that the basement bath will not drain as well only when the vanities are being used?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. The harder your question is to read, the less likely you'll get a good answer, so you might want to edit a bit. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.