# Basement plumbing vent

Tags: plumbing

RE: I am installings a basement bath (toilet, shower and sink) Saniflo macerating  pump system.
The house has a 3" vent pipe going from the basement ceiling thru the roof to vent the pump system into.
However, there are 2 vanities on the first floor above the basement using this 3" vent pipe for both their drains and vents. 
Question 1:  Since the vanities use the vent as a drain (for about 2 feet) from the first floor (above the basement), can the pump system be workably vented into it.
Question 2:  Is the only possible drawback being the fact that the basement pump vent may be impeded when the vanities are draining?(not asking about any codes) Thanks

Comment: Why does this seem like a nearly identical duplicate of [this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/182575/can-a-basement-bathroom-be-vented-through-a-stack-servicing-sinks-on-the-floor-a#comment318136_182575)?

Comment: It was suggested to reword it for clarification, so I did.  ...new here, sorry if didn't do it correctly

Comment: You've posted as two different users, and there's an edit button on your post. Please pick one account, delete one question, and revise as needed. We'll be happy to help.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. You can [request that the two accounts be merged](//diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.